# Removal of columns in data frame with the lowest variances. (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with 1000 observations and 100 variables and I want to remove some variables, more precisely I want to remove the  75 variables with the lowest variance so that I get a `df` of 1000 observations and 25 variables.

I did this:

```
newDf = df[, sapply(df, var) > variance]
```

where I chose variance such that `ncol(newDf) == 25`. But this for some reason does not give me a new data frame with highest variances since there are a lot of columns with low variances left in the new data frame and many high-variance columns are removed. Am I misunderstanding that line of code?

I've also looked into the `filter()` function in `dplyr` but I can't filter based on column variance there.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: I tried your code on a small example and it worked perfectly,

Comment: to echo @LMc: this looks like it should work, so a [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
newDF = df[, head(order(sapply(df, var), decreasing = TRUE), 25)]
```

Comment: This does indeed work well. However newDF is now sorted based on variance but I want only to remove the columns with lowest variance and preserve the order in the original df. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Parseval just match the columns in the order they appear in the original dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simulation of a dataframe of your size and how I'd have solved it using `purrr::map_dbl`.

```
vardf <- map_dfc(sample(1:100, size = 100), ~ rnorm(1000, 0, .x))
colsd <- map_dbl(vardf, sd)
to_remove <- colsd <= sort(colsd)[75]
newdf <- vardf[, !to_remove]
```

You could of course do that in just one or two lines, but I find this more legible.